# Nginx self-signed certificates for gRPC server

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, grpc

I want to set up a gRPC service behind nginx that also serves letsencrypt enabled https services. I want to enable and disable access from client services (other websites) on a regular basis. So if CompanyC joins I ill give them a client certificate and add it to my nginx configuration. My gRPC will serve multiple clients and each would have a separate client certificate.

Is this sane? The goal is to provide secure gRPC access. See also [this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/834684/nginx-with-multiple-certificates-letsencrypt-and-self-signed) which answers how.